# How to get a list of warnings from next.js terminal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, next.js, console.log

When i run my project with VScode, i see a lot of warnings in my terminal. The example of such warning:

```
 The `bg-variant` mixin has been deprecated as of v4.4.0. It will be removed entirely in v5.
         on line 8 of node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_deprecate.scss, in mixin `deprecate`
         from line 15 of node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_background-variant.scss, in mixin `bg-variant`
         from line 256 of src/styles/_utils.scss
         from line 23 of stdin
```

How can i get these warnings from the VSCode terminal into my JS code and handle them? (in example, log them in browser console or store in an array)

Comment: You can't because they run on the server side. You should handle them by removing deprecated code.

Comment: Thanks. Should i delete my question since it can't be answered?

Answer (score 0):

One way is that you can run

```
npm run build
```

Running this command will list all the warnings and errors (including eslint errors and warnings) that won't be displayed when running `npm run dev`.

PS: Running `npm run build` will build the project in `.next` at the project's root. Make sure to add the folder in `.gitignore` if you do not need the build files.

Hope this helps, good luck with your project!